# Create collections inside migrations

Tags: django, collections, migration, wagtail

I want create migrations for create **collections** applying one migration.

I haven't clear which is the properly workflow for create **collections** since python code, can anyone help to me?

Comment: I made more clearly the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, searching in the web i found two solutions:
one in ***[google mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wagtail/collection%7Csort:relevance/wagtail/NGEPyEbTUHA/Z5J49yY5AwAJ)***, and other here in ***[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178845/create-collection-with-python-code)***.

After test the code in the shell we can see that it works for create collections:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Collection
root_coll = Collection.get_first_root_node()
root_coll.add_child(name='testcoll')
```

Now we can use this code but in a migration, so, create a new empty migration with `./manage.py makemigrations home --empty` and add inside the previous code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Collection


def create_collections(apps, schema_editor):
    names = [
        'video tutoriales',
        'videos personal',
        'videos varios',
        'imagenes tutoriales',
        'imagenes personal',
        'imaganes varias',
        'documentos tutoriales',
        'documentos personal',
        'documentos varios'
    ]
    # Get models

    # Get collection's root
    root_collection = Collection.get_first_root_node()

    for name in names:
        root_collection.add_child(name=name)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('home', '0002_create_homepage'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_collections),
    ]
```

First, we get the main `Collection` node in a variable, after we add whatever amount of child with his respective name.

Is a very basic code actually.

If anyone can optimize it, your welcome, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Does something as mentioned here would work?

[How to squash recent Django migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028586/how-to-squash-recent-django-migrations)

`python manage.py squashmigrations <appname> <squashfrom> <squashto>`

Regards

Comment: Consider explaining or elaborating your answer so it can help other users, it is very unclear how it solves the problem